# How to find a dynamically created element in the code behind file by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to access the `aSubchapter` in the JavaScript file, what should I have to do?(this page is content page)

in .aspx.cs file

```
protected void page_load()
{
  HtmlGenericControl aSubchapter=new HtmlGenericControl("a");
  aSubchapter.Attributes.Add("href","somevalue");
  aSubchapter.ID="subchapter";
}
```

in .aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var subchap=document.getElementById('<%=subchapter.ClientID%>');
    //(The above lines says that subchap is undefined)
</script>
```

Comment: Try using `document.getElementById('subchapter')` because `<a>` is not server control

Comment: even i tried that but it is saying undefined

Comment: does the control gets rendered at the page ? Try executing your code after the load `document.onload = function() { /*run code here */}`

Comment: try this: `aSubchapter.Attributes.Add("id", "subchapter");` instead of `aSubchapter.ID="subchapter";`

Answer (score 0):

Since you created the control in the code behind you need to add it to the page. It will not be visible until you add it to some control.

Generally, you define a  control in .aspx file and add the controls as child from code behind.